# JasperReports as Tomcat default application in URL

Tags: docker, tomcat, bitnami, jasperserver

Standard deployment of jasperreports  (`docker pull bitnami/jasperreports` - under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jasperServerDB:
    container_name: jasperServerDB
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './jasperServerDB_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_USER=mariaDbUser
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mariaDbPassword
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=jasperServerDB
  jasperServer:
    container_name: jasperServer
    image: docker.io/bitnami/jasperreports:latest
    ports:
      - '8085:8080'
    volumes:
      - './jasperServer_data:/bitnami/jasperreports'
    depends_on:
      - jasperServerDB
    environment:
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_HOST=jasperServerDB
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_USER=dbUser
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=dbPassword
      - JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_NAME=jasperServerDB
      - JASPERREPORTS_USERNAME=adminUser
      - JASPERREPORTS_PASSWORD=adminPassword
    restart: on-failure
```

The reporting server is behind nginx reverse proxy which points to port 8085 of the docker machine.

Everything works as expected on https://my.domain.com/jasperserver/ url.

It is required to have JasperReports server responding on only https://my.domain.com/ url.

[image]

What is the recommended/best approach to configure the container (default Tomcat application) which **can survive** container's **restarts** and **updates**?

Some results from searching the net:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tomcat/HowTo#HowTo-HowdoImakemywebapplicationbetheTomcatdefaultapplication?
https://coderanch.com/t/85615/application-servers/set-application-default-application
https://benhutchison.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/how-to-configure-tomcat-root-context/

Which doubtfully are applicable to bitnami containers.

Hopefully there is a simple image configuration which could be included in the docker-compose.yml file.

[Reference to GitHub Bitnami JasperReports Issues List where the same question is posted.](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-jasperreports/issues/109)

Answer (score 1):

After trying all recommended ways to achieve the requirement, seems that Addendum 1 from [cwiki.apache.org](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tomcat/HowTo#HowTo-HowdoImakemywebapplicationbetheTomcatdefaultapplication?) is the best one.

Submitted a PR to bitnami with single parameter fix of the use case: [ROOT URL setting](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-jasperreports/pull/110)

Here is a workaround in case the above PR doesn't get accepted

**Step 1**

Create a .sh (e.g `start.sh`) file in the docker-compose.yml folder with following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose up -d
echo "Building JasperReports Server..."
#Long waiting period to ensure the container is up and running (health checks didn't worked out well)
sleep 180;
echo "...completed!"
docker exec -u 0 -it jasperServer sh -c "rm -rf /opt/bitnami/tomcat/webapps/ROOT && rm /opt/bitnami/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver && ln -s /opt/bitnami/jasperreports /opt/bitnami/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"
echo "Ready to rock!"
```

Note that the container name must match the one from your docker-compose.yml file.

**Step 2**

Start the container by typing: `$sh ./start.sh` instead of `$docker-compose up -d`.

**Step 3**

Give it some time and try https://my.domain.com/.